# See all GIT conflicts on terminal window

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

I would like to know if GIT has a command that allows me to see all conflicts and conflicts per file on the terminal window. I would like to see **only** the conflicts on the terminal window without having to open the file on a code editor (either an IDE or nano, vim, and the like). I will most likely fix the conflicts using an IDE but I would like to see them all first. Once I fix the conflicts I would like to run a command to make sure there are no more conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `git diff` with the right filter here :

```
git diff --diff-filter=U
```

I have not tested it though.

Comment: I will try it out next time I have a conflict.